# call a function multiple times with kwargs in a list [python]

Tags: python, filter, keyword-argument

Do I need to define this function, or does it already exist in python? I guess it's something to do with map, but I want to pass in a list of dicts, which get ** expanded when the function is called, not passed in directly, and my search results are hijacked by general kwargs stuff.

```
def doublestarmap(fn, kwargs_list):
    '''run function fn for each kwargs in kwargs_list'''
    return [fn(**kwargs) for kwargs in kwargs_list]
```

Specifically, I'd like this to be a function so I can call it in a separate thread.

```
def foo(a, b):
    print(a, b)


kwargs_list = [
    dict(a=1, b=2),
    dict(a=10, b=20),
    dict(a=100, b=200),
]
doublestarmap(foo, kwargs_list)  # sanity check
thread = threading.Thread(
    target=doublestarmap,
    kwargs=dict(fn=foo, kwargs_list=kwargs_list),
)
thread.start()
```

That last bit about running in the thread is key. I want to be able to send a list of kwargs, and a function to a thread, and it runs the function with each kwargs dict one after the other. My code above works fine. I just don't want to reinvent the wheel with my own `doublestarmap` function, if there's a more pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: IIUC, you want to call `fn` several times with different args?

Comment: There's [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) but I don't think there's a `doublestarmap`. :)

Comment: @RafaelC yes, but with the specifications as detailed in the post

Comment: @timgeb, ah yes, it's basically a doublestarmap isn't it. If it doesn't exist in python already, I'll rename my function to that then, makes more sense.